# How can I balance the weight of two individual shapes in a logo?

Tags: logo, typography, designers, calligraphy

I'm creating my own avatar with letters **V** and **K**. Now, I like the idea that I have used but I'm finding it difficult to "balance" the logo. Please see image. Left part is for V and right part is for K. (See explanation on right in image: Yellow colored area is for **V**, Red is to represent **K**)

The 1st design has equal widths for both shapes (**x units**), so mathematically seems fine, but I find the **K** part is little "heavy / thick" as compared to **V**.

I tried to fix it by slightly decreasing the width (**x-1 units**) and now it seems "balanced" (at least to me) as widths "seem" equal.

I'm really confused which design is better.

[image]

Which design is aesthetically looks better? Is it okay to break such a rule (by decreasing widths) to balance something and make it look aesthetically better?

Comment: Take the ruler that you use for this and throw it away. **There are no rules in graphic design** is the only "rule" you must keep in mind. Which one do YOU like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think both options are kind of ok, but your reasoning is fine: the mathematical version is slightly tilting to the right, so an optical correction is good to decrease the width of the `K` part. I would choose the second, adjusted version. See:

- https://www.adweek.com/creativity/how-the-imperfections-in-googles-logo-are-what-make-it-perfect/
- https://medium.com/@lukejones/optical-adjustment-b55492a1165c

Comment: Do professional designers do such adjustments and break rules? I'm a beginner and really interested to know this.

Comment: I just read this article. https://logogeek.uk/logo-design/optical-corrections/ I guess I'm facing the same problem? That's what optical correction?

Comment: Yes optical corrections are found in commercial fonts and probably well known logos. Go for it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second option is better, but...

You can add a bit of interest to your logo with a typographic resource: **stroke modulation**

The V lacks a stroke, which suggests that it is a typography with modulated strokes like **Optima Extra Black**

[image: Optima]

If we look the K of the same typography, the modulation is in the upper inclined stroke

[image: Optima K]

Following this, the construction could be something like this:

[image: logo]

Comment: Happy to learn this technique but I feel 2nd looks better. If you scale down the logo you suggested, it wouldn't look cool. Hope you understand. Still many many thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it depends what you are looking for, I am not so fan of symmetry. Actually I will exaggerate more the modulation. Sometimes I prefer the uniqueness than looking "cool". Good job!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could correct the illusion that the K is too thick. But there are no rules for this.  Do what you think looks best.

One way is to cut into the inner angle of the K.

For example:

[image]